# Render called before setState updates state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate, asynchronous-javascript

Is there any way to make sure `render` is called after `setState` actually updates the state? From my knowledge, `setState` is asynchronous. I have tried putting `render` as the callback to `setState`, but it still renders before the state is updated.

HTML code:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

React code:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            squares: []
        };
        this.create = this.create.bind(this);
    }

    create() {
        console.log('squares before: ' + this.state.squares);
        var a = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            a.push(undefined);
        }
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
        a[i] = 2;
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 8;
        a[i] = 2;
        console.log('new squares: ' + squares);
        console.log('non-updated squares: ' + this.state.squares);
        this.setState({
            squares: a
        }, console.log('updated squares: ' + this.state.squares);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.create();
    }

    render() {
        console.log('rendering');
        return (<div>
                <table className="table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[0]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[1]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[2]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[3]}/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[4]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[5]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[6]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[7]}/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[8]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[9]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[10]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[11]}/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[12]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[13]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[14]}/></td>
                            <td className="td"><Number number={this.state.squares[15]}/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>);
    }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
    newGame() {
        this.refs.table.create();
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <Table ref="table"/>
            <button id="newGame" onClick={this.newGame.bind(this)}>New Game</button>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Basically, what happens in this is that 'rendering' gets logged first and then 'updated squares: ...' like this:

```
squares before: [undefined, 2, undefined, undefined, undefined, 2]
new squares: [undefined, undefined, 2, undefined, 2, undefined]
non-updated squares: [undefined, 2, undefined, undefined, undefined, 2]
rendering
updated squares: [undefined, undefined, 2, undefined, 2, undefined]
```

I tried making the callback to `setState` `render`, but the second render would render after the first render but before `setState` updated `state`:

```
this.setState({
  squares: a
}, this.render);
```

It logged:

```
squares before: [undefined, 2, undefined, undefined, undefined, 2]
new squares: [undefined, undefined, 2, undefined, 2, undefined]
non-updated squares: [undefined, 2, undefined, undefined, undefined, 2]
rendering
rendering
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `synchronous` `setState` in `componentWillMount` doesn't trigger a re-render instead reflects the change in the initial render itself.The callback to setState however is called after the render method.

If you log the `state squares` inside the render method, it will log the correct result in the initial render itself.

**P.S.** `componentWillMount` is deprecated in the latest versions and its better to have your current logic in constructor instead of `componentWillMount`

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/m54wl6wz9y)

Comment: But how do you fix the code so that it renders after setState is called?

Comment: @VapporWashmade,you present code will call render only after setState is called and updates state, only the callback to setState is triggered afterwards

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have the a similar question. Is there a precondition that the `render` method will only be called after the state really been changed.

Answer (score 0):

use shouldComponentUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState), for render, each time it returns true, render will happen